# Xamarin Forms: error in Droid project with Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

there are three day I'm trying to have a clear solution to start for each platform. Unfortunately, I'm very frustrating because I can't have that. Now in droid project there is a new kind of error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/view/VelocityTrackerCompat;

I tried to build and rebuild the project a lot of times without success. What have to do?

[image: Android references in the project]

Then I tried to update my Droid solution but the result is wrong then before.

I googled a bit but obviuosly I can't find a solution or anyone with my same problem. Visual Studio 2015 shows my a lot of errors.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

The version of Xamarin Studio is old.

[image: Nuget Update]

This is the new list of references for the Droid project. I don't know what I can do now...

[image: List of references after the update]

Comment: Update the Forms package to the latest version, but do not update the Android support packages as they may be incompatible. If you already updated the support packages yourself, uninstall them and then reinstall the Forms package and it will also install the correct support packages as dependencies. Then make sure to set the Android project's "Compile version" option to ["Use latest platform"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Android).

Comment: Could be possible that you are using Xlabs?

Comment: Hi @jimmgarr thanks for your comment. I resolve my issue to remove all references and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I removed all references from the Droid project and then I reinstalled all references.

Now it's working fine.